# Position records in database table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, position, records

Lets say I have a table called "pages" , fields : id , name , content , position.
When I display all pages in my cms , I want to put "down" and "up" buttons to set page position.
How I do the position update ? **how I know how to reposition the other pages ?**

For example:

```
id  name  content  position
1   Home  bla bla  1
2   Info  bla bla  4
```

If I click "up" for the second page(Info) the position need to update to 1 and the first page position need to be bigger than 1 - like 2.

I use MySQL database , I need solution on PHP.

Comment: Sort position and swap up and down

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not posting any code I can't give a specific solution, but I can give you a general one. It would be something like this (not tested)

Decrease the position of your page (assuming it's name is in `$pageName`, and that the table name is `pages`) like this:

```
  mysql_query("UPDATE `pages` SET position=position-1 WHERE name=$pageName");
```

You might want to check that the rank is >0 first, if you don't allow negative rank. Increase the position of the page that now has the same rank as the current page

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE `pages` SET position=position+1 
        WHERE position = (SELECT position FROM `pages` WHERE name=$pageName) 
        AND NOT name=".$pageName)
```

This of course assumes that there is no UNIQUE constraint on the page ranks. If there is, do something like:

1. Select the rank for the page you want to edit (say to `$thisRank`
2. Select the id of the page with rank `$thisRank-1`, i.e. the one above (say to `$aboveId`) to an unused rank.
3. Set the rank of your page to `$thisRank-1`
4. Set the rank of `$aboveId` to `$thisRank`

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish that is to submit on the same page. For example position.php

If you have 3 records, consider:

John bla bla (position 1)
Mary bla bla (position 2)
George bla bla (position 3)

At first you need a link like this

```
    <a href="position.php?position=<?=$position?>&id=<?=$id?>">up</a>
```

The $position is the current position of the element as you see above and the id is the id of your table.

When you click on that link with

```
    $_GET['position'] and $_GET['id']
```

you have the position and the id of the current record.

So you can do the following

```
 <?php
         //connect to DB

         if(isset($_GET['position']) && isset($_GET['id'])){
           $line = $_GET['position'];    
          $id = $_GET['id'];
          //if line is not the first one    
         if($line!=1){       

        $query = "select id,position from pages where position<$line order by position   desc limit 0,1";
       $result = mysql_query($query);
       $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
       $gotoLine = $row['position'];//line to go to
       $idLine = $row['id'];
       //one position up
       $queryUpdate = "update pages set position=$gotoLine where id=$id";
       mysql_query($queryUpdate);
       //one position down
       $queryUpdate2 = "update pages set position=$line where id=$idLine";
       mysql_query($queryUpdate2);

   }     
}

   $queryLinks = "select * from pages order by position";
   $resultLinks = mysql_query($queryLinks);
   while($rowLinks = mysql_fetch_array($resultLinks)){

   $name = $rowLinks['name'];
   $id = $rowLinks['id'];
   $position = $rowLinks['position'];

   echo "$name<a href='position.php?position=$position&id=$id'> up </a><br/>";

}    


?>
```